# ExtJS singleton utility class alias

Tags: javascript, class, extjs, singleton

In ExtJS 6.2 I would like to create singleton static utility classes, for example `util.string`, `util.math`, and in my code I would call functions on those like this `util.math.sqrt(x);`

When I need to use those classes I have to import them:

```js
Ext.define('MyAPP.Application', {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

   name: 'MyAPP',

   requires: [
      'MyAPP.Util.math',
      'MyAPP.Util.string',
   ]
});
```

But to use I have to type `MyAPP.Util.math.sqrt(x)`, I would like to just have to use `util.math.sqrt(x);`, I tried using alias, but it doesn't work for me:

```js
Ext.define('MyAPP.Util.math', {
   alias: 'util.math',
   singleton: true,
});
```

Using `alternateClassName: 'util.math'` works, but it seems that `alternateClassName` should only be used for backward compatibility.

Comment: I use `alternameClassName` for my singletons. Why do you think it is not intended this way? ExtJS 7.4 docs still lists this property for `Ext.Class` and it is not marked as deprecated.

Comment: Hi @PeterKoltai it's not deprecated, but I remember seeing comments saying that it was intended for backwards compatibility with very old versions of ExtJS.

Comment: I think that the ExtJS framework uses it for establishing its own backwards compatibility with older versions. Doesn't mean you should not use `alternateClassName` for your own purposes.